# Is triple digging worth the backache in temperate biomes?

Tags: soil

I read in [Tips for the Lazy Gardener](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1580170269) that gardens in drier parts of Africa can be triple dug (as opposed to double dug, or as I prefer, barely dug) which will somehow absorb more water during the rainy season and store it for the remainder of the growing season.

What conditions would prompt a person, not living in a desert or savannah, to triple dig their garden?

Comment: *"What conditions would prompt a person, not living in a desert or savannah, to triple dig their garden?",* insanity or the need for a **really! good workout**. [Shane's answer](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/7/is-triple-digging-worth-the-backache-in-temperate-biomes/296#296) is a good one, double-digging & plenty of added organic matter should be more than enough for most people.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think anyone with loose sand or hard clay soil could probably benefit from triple digging.  I've never personally gone to this extent though.  However, my native soil is compact clay and I've found that the soil I've spent more time working additional organic material into tend to produce happier plants.